# Converting an array to ChartJS-required format

Tags: angular, chart.js

i'm trying to take data returned from an api and convert it to match the structure that is needed by ChartJS.

This is the format which is required by ChartJS:

```js
  data: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {data: [80, 90, 100], label: 'Customer 1'},
    {data: [100, 80, 70], label: 'Customer 2'},
    {data: [60, 80, 70], label: 'Customer 3'},
  ];
```

This is the JSON data that I am using:

```json
{
  "transaction_date": "2021-07-13T10:38:20.661",
  "value": 970.420000000000,
  "customer_name": "Customer 1",
},
{
  "transaction_date": "2021-07-13T10:38:20.661",
  "gross_value": 20.000000000000,
  "customer_name": "Customer 2",
},
{
  "transaction_date": "2021-07-13T10:38:20.661",
  "gross_value": 19.000000000000,
  "customer_name": "Customer 1",
},
{
  "transaction_date": "2021-07-14T11:50:15",
  "gross_value": 73.150000000000,
  "customer_name": "Customer 1",
},
{
  "transaction_date": "2021-07-15T10:38:20.661",
  "gross_value": 19.000000000000,
  "customer_name": "Customer 3",
}
```

And i've created an array of chart dates:

```js
chartDates = [
    "2021-07-13",
    "2021-07-14",
    "2021-07-15",
];
```

This is the function I made to sort the data into the format needed by ChartJS. I am mapping the customer name and looping through the chart dates to split the data into 3 days.

```js
  chartJsData(data) {
    const labels = [];
    const graphData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i].customer.map((a) => {
        if (!this[a.customer_name]) {
          this[a.customer_name] = {customer_name: a.customer_name, gross_value: 0};
          const label = name;
          const totals = [0, 0, 0];
          const date = a.transaction_date;
          // this.chartDates.length is 3
          for (let j = 0; i < this.chartDates.length; j++) {
            // If the transaction date is within the chart dates sum the totals
            if (j !== 2 && date >= this.chartDates[i].toISOString() && date <= this.chartDates[j + 1].toISOString()) {
              totals[i] += a.gross_value;
              break;
            } else if (date <= this.chartDates[i].toISOString()) {
              totals[i] += a.gross_value;
              break;
            }
          }
          graphData.push({data: totals, label, stack: 'a'});
          labels.push(a.customer_name);
        }
        labels.push(a.customer_name);
      }, Object.create(null));
      this.lineChartData = graphData;
    }
  }
```

The function seems to be only returning one transaction rather than splitting them by days. If anyone can see what i'm doing wrong or suggest a better way of doing this please let me know.